# Is it possible to install IIS 6 on a windows 7 machine?

Tags: iis

Is it possible to install IIS 6.0 on a windows 7 machine? If I go through add windows features, it doesn't give me an option to install IIS 6.

When I searched on google I came across alternatives such as [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43132/How-to-Setup-IIS-6-0-on-Windows-7-to-Allow-Classic). But I was just curious if what I am asking is possible. On one hand IIS is just a software, so you'd guess it is possible. On the other hand it is integrated so deep into the windows operating system, maybe there is no way to achieve it without modifying the operating system itself. I wonder if there are any insiders from Microsoft who would have some insight into this.

Comment: I also have the same doubt. I want IIS 6(not only the console or manager), it means the actual IIS server. With Windows/Vista 7 i got IIS 7.X but now what is i want another or replace this with IIS 6. Isnt there any another way. I went through [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397374(v=exchg.80).aspx) and it gave some option as IIS compatiblity mode. Is this same as installing IIS 6 on my machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I talked to one of the Microsoft experts at my work place. IIS 6.0 can ONLY be installed on Windows 2003 server. IIS 5.0 onwards, IIS has been tied to the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the tools for [Vista](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732269.aspx) instead.

If you're looking to administer classic ASP sites on a Windows 7 machine, there still are options though. Check out this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43132/How-to-Setup-IIS-6-0-on-Windows-7-to-Allow-Classic).