# Visual Studio 2003 Prerequisites on Windows 7

Tags: .net, visual-studio, iis, iis-7, .net-1.1

I am trying to install `Visual Studio 2003` on `Windows 7`.  We have a web app here that was written in VS2003 that I need to support.

When the installation starts it does a prerequisites check and tells me that is needs:

- IIS to be installed and
- Frontpage server extensions

I know for a fact that IIS is installed.  But why would it be asking me to install it?  Am I missing something here?

And what about Frontpage server extensions?  Do I just ignore this?  If not where do I get this from?

When I go to programs and features select turn widowns features on and off I have the following selected:

Internet Information Services -> Web Management Tools -> IIS6 Management Compatibility:

- IIS 6 Management Console
- IIS 6 Scripting Tools
- IIS 6 WMI Compatibility
- IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility

Answer (score 1):

probably VS is trying to detect IIS 6.0, Windows 7 comes with IIS 7 / 7.5 if you want to configure IIS 7 for classic ASP look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43132/How-to-Setup-IIS-6-0-on-Windows-7-to-Allow-Classic however look at the discussion regarding installing IIS 6: [Is it possible to install IIS 6 on a windows 7 machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689393/is-it-possible-to-install-iis-6-on-a-windows-7-machine)

don't try to install frontpage extensions on IIs 7, look a this post : http://forums.iis.net/p/1160144/1913961.aspx

hope it helps,